Tailwind CSS Class Not Applying Styles In VS Code
I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS in my project, but the Tailwind classes are not applying styles as expected. Here’s a minimal example of my setup:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="bg-red-600">
  <center><h1>Hello world!</h1></center>
</body>
</html>

Here is my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/*.{html}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

And here is my File Pathing:

However when I use Style="" it works completely fine.

Tailwind Installation: I have Tailwind CSS installed and included in my project.

CSS File: The input.css file includes the Tailwind directives:

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


Build Process: I am using npx tailwindcss -o output.css to compile the CSS.

File Path: The path to output.css in the <link> tag is correct.

Cache: I’ve cleared my browser cache and tried a hard refresh.


Despite these steps, the bg-red-600 class is not applying the red background color. When using inline styles like style="background-color: red;", it works fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide the tailwind.config.js file and where your source code is located.

edited the question and added! Thanks!

There are a couple of suspicious things: 1. output.css does not appear to be in the /public directory; 2. npx tailwindcss does not appear to specify an input file

I have changed the output.css to style.css because of what i am used to. Could that name change be the problem?

If everything is renamed accordingly, there shouldn't be a problem. Can you see the compiled class names in the style.css file?

I believe everything is fine in that sense. The thing that is so strange to me is that when I use Style="" it works perfectly fine. However when I use class="" it does not.

I checked again, there isn't a problem there. And there shouldn't be because style="" works.

Its fixed now. Had to use <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> in the html file,
